# Profiler for java-based web application?

Tags: java, profiling, performance

There are a number of questions related to profiling a java application, but I'm wondering if these recommendations also apply to profiling a web-based (tomcat) java application?

Are there specific tools that a better than others?  Or is the assumption that most java applications these days are web-based, and the existing questions/recommendations apply to web based applications?

Comment: jconsole|visualvm/jmap/jstack is all you need, all come w/ the standard jdk.

Answer (score 4):

You can start with jvisualvm in the Sun 6 JDK which allows you to attach to a running JVM and gather basic memory and cpu profiling data.  This allows you to get a rough idea of what is going on, and if better profiilng tools are necessary.

Comment: It is a stand alone version of the one in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), [JProbe](http://www.quest.com/jprobe/), and [DynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/). DynaTrace is the most expensive choice but I found it as the most useful one so far. They also have a DynaTrace Ajax Client that's free and lets you profile on the front end side (java script execution, ajax calls, rendering time, etc). You can also use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture execution times.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [JAMon](http://www.jamonapi.com), App Dynamics Lite, and [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) and found JavaMelody to be the best and most compatible of each of them.  It is easy to install and provides all the data you need to find the slow web requests, jsp pages, errors, and sql queries.  It provides great summary data and charts.  It also has very little overhead so it could be used in production instances.  It will show you your cpu, ram, and thread utilization.  You can't drill down to the nitty gritty per-line profiling like other tools, but it can point you in the right direction to find bottlenecks.